# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 SQL Select Clause with Condition

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, native

I am creating a Form in Symfony2 and I would like to fill a dropdown with the results of a custom query. Here is an example php code:

```
<?php
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...
        ->add('type', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'EventBundle:Event',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->add('select', 'e.id, CONCAT(IF (e.modified > NOW(), "Pending: ", ""), e.name) as name')
                ;
            }
        ))
    ;
}
?>
```

I cannot find a way to set this SELECT clause though. I am looking to something similar to "new Zend_Db_Expr(...)" in Zend Framework.
Is there a way of achieving creating this query with the complex SELECT clause withoug typing it as native SQL code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the query you're providing is supposed to be DQL, not SQL.

And seeing how IF() is [not valid DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), I'm not sure what you can do to fix this.  Perhaps let the Entity class itself do the concatenation by way of the [property option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property)?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...
        ->add('type', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'EventBundle:Event',
            'property'      => 'modifiedName',
        ))
    ;
}
```

And then in EventBundle\Entity\Event

```
public function getModifiedName()
{
  return $this->modified > new \DateTime() 
    ? 'Pending: ' . $this->getName()
    : $this->getName()
  ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, my question is basically how to write IF and CONCAT in the SELECT clause using DQL. If "IF" is not valid in DQL, then I should stick to your suggestion of using PHP logic instead, although my opinion is that generally if something can be done in the database, it should be done in the database, not in PHP.